# Googlebot causing JavaScript errors

Tags: javascript, googlebot

Looking through our logs, we always see not defined JavaScript errors caused by Googlebot.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
```

This is the user agent string for all these errors.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.92 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

In our code, we have the function defined in a separate file and then reference it in our view templates.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/js/my-script.js?v=1.4"></script>

<script>
    $('document').ready(function(){
        if (typeof myFunction != 'undefined') {
            myFunction.init();
        }
    });
</script>
```

The JS file contains an IIFE assigned to a variable, that looks like this:

```
var myFunction = (function () {
    var init = function () {
        // do stuff
    };

    return { init: init };
})();
```

This works fine for all devices except the googlebot. Why would googlebot be creating these errors when myFunction is wrapped in a check for undefined?

Comment: if (typeof myFunction != 'undefined')  --> use two equals --> if (typeof myFunction !== 'undefined')

Comment: Thanks @JoelGarciaNuño, but that does not seem to have resolved the issue.